# subprocess.call format for ffmpeg|sed command?

Tags: python, sed, ffmpeg, subprocess

These are the command I want to execute using subprocess.call in python

```
 1. ffmpeg -i filename 2>&1 | sed -n "s/.*, \(.*\) fp.*/\1/p"

  filePath = frames/FRAME%05d.png
 2. avconv -r 24 -i filePath -vf 'scale=trunc(iw/2)*2:trunc(ih/2)*2' -s 1920x1080 -c:v libx264 outPath
```

I haven't gotten around to 2nd one yet but here is my try for first one

```
subprocess.call(['ffmpeg', '-i', inputV , '2','>','&1', '|', ' sed', '-n', '"s/.*, \(.*\) fp.*/\1/p"'])
```

and This is the error

```
[NULL @ 0x915ce0] Unable to find a suitable output format for '2'
2: Invalid argument
```

I am also not sure about the filePath variable assignment as the value includes wildcards

Comment: try with `shell=True`

Comment: The first line of the error is not a shell or parsing error. ffmpeg, unlike ffprobe, is a media convertor. So it requires an output argument. Add `-f null -` before `2>&1`

Comment: @Mulvya actually the above line can be used to extract information from the media, without actually converting anything.

Comment: I didn't say otherwise. Only pointing out why the first line error occurs.

Comment: @Mulvya the fact that `2` is passed to ffmpeg means that it's not interpreted by the shell, because the shell is not involved, but should be.

Comment: Yes, that's a different error also present. If an output isn't specified, like I suggested, errorlevel will be set to 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quickfix: add `shell=True` option since you're using shell features.

Longfix: write a proper `subprocess.Popen` command, and get rid of `sed`: do it in python directly:

```
import re
r = re.compile(".*, (.*) fp.*")
p=subprocess.Popen(['ffmpeg', '-i', inputV],stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
while True:
  l = p.readline()
  if not l:
      break  # end of process
  s = r.sub(l,r"\1")
  if l!=s:    # substitution worked, print it
     print(s)
rc = p.wait()  # get return code
```

so you're not using `shell=True` like that, and you perform the `sed` filter within python: your code doesn't need `sed` anymore.

And `stderr=subprocess.STDOUT` takes care of `stderr` redirection in `stdout`